# Vulkan is not freeing all memory

Tags: c++, allocation, vulkan

I have been following the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/), and I have noticed that Vulkan is not freeing all memory that is being allocated.

The code below simply creates and destroys a Vulkan instance and overloads the new and delete operators to keep track of how many times memory is being allocated and freed.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

int counter = 0;

void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    void* buffer = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes at location: " << buffer << " [ Counter = " << ++counter << " ]" << std::endl;
    return buffer;
}
void operator delete(void* buffer)
{
    std::cout << "Freeing at location: " << buffer << " [ Counter = " << --counter << " ]" << std::endl;
    free(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    VkInstance instance;

    VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo {};
    applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "Test";
    applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    applicationInfo.pEngineName = "No engine";
    applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo {};
    instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

    if(vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, NULL, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to create a vulkan instance" << std::endl;

    vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);

    glfwTerminate();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code above runs fine but the final console output displays:

`Freeing at location: 0x558c0c42fda0 [ Counter = 58 ]`

Meaning that 58 buffers of memory have been allocated without being freed, and there could potentially be more if malloc and free were being used alongside the new and delete operators.

Am I missing any sort of destruction function which is responsible for freeing this memory? Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: Vulkan is a C API, what makes you think it would use your custom overloads for `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Should be zero allocations, because outside library should not even be using your overloads. You could put breakpoints there and look at the stack to determine where this is coming from.

Comment: @krOoze Thanks for the suggestion of adding breakpoints, I debugged the program with gdb and found that most calls to operator new and delete were called from libLLVM.so. I also noted that libstdc++.so did very few calls to operator new but never called operator delete. Both of these libraries are C++ based libraries.